# Scale value needed to shrink one circle to match another?

Tags: math, geometry

I have a couple of circles that share the same center point. Both are already scaled down from a larger circle.

I know each circle's radius rather easily. I only have the larger circles "scale" value. Given each circle can have a random scale value that makes the circle larger and smaller (and gives it a new radius), I'm trying to figure out how much *more* I need to scale that outer circle down to *match* the smaller circle's radius.

On a programming level, I've tried scaling down the larger circle at very large iterations until match -- but that is really tedious. And I'd like to understand the math behind this all.

Does anyone know how I might go about solving this?

[image]

Comment: What's the relationship between `Radius`, `Scale value`, and the actual drawing radius?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be posted on math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does proportion

```
ScaleB = ScaleA * RadiusB / RadiusA = 0.498 * 0.637 / 1.936 = 0.164
```

work for you?